# Java applet repaint after thread sleep

Tags: java, applet, awt, mouseclick-event

I have a rather simple applet I am trying to make - once the mouse is clicked, we repaint with a new string. This is essentially a countdown (3,2,1...exit). However, the applet doesn't seem to want to repaint until AFTER the sleep loop is over. See code:

```
        public void paint(Graphics g){
      g.setColor(Color.blue);
      g.stringtoprint(s1,300,150);

      }



public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mev) {
    mouseClicked = true;
    int j = 0;

    while(j<=3){

        if (j < 3)
        {
        stringtoprint = "Self destruct in: " + (3-j);
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);

        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){}
        finally{            

        System.out.println("click!");} -- this line works in the console
        this.repaint(); --doesn't repaint until countdown is over(and then exits)
        }
        else {System.exit(0);} --exits applet when j=3
        j++;
    }
```

I suspect this is something with the mouseevent that overrides the paint event? I'm confused

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [java thread.sleep puts swing ui to sleep too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215968/java-thread-sleep-puts-swing-ui-to-sleep-too)