# Why does this while loop prevent paint method from working correctly?

Tags: java, netbeans, while-loop, jframe, jpanel

Here's my code:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JavaApplication2 extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Sketching Program");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JavaApplication2());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);

        while(true) {
            delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still trying to get the hang of things here.
Now if the while(true) loop is commented out, it works fine, and the screen is covered in black.
I've even put it in repaint() and called it from paint, and that does the same thing. I'm sure I'm miles from making this fine. If there's things I'm doing wrong, could you inform me? I've been looking everywhere to get this to work, and couldn't find anything that applied. Thank you.

Comment: umm why do you have an infinite loop in the first place?

Comment: Side note: in Swing classes (e.g. JPanel) you are not supposed to override the `paint` method, but rather the `paintComponent` method.

Comment: You hire a painter to repaint your house. He comes to your house and is ready to start painting, but every second, you tell him "no, please wait one more second". Will your house be painted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java thread.sleep puts swing ui to sleep too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215968/java-thread-sleep-puts-swing-ui-to-sleep-too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because painting happens in the `Event Dispatch Thread`, and you're blocking it with your obvious infinite loop. This will prevent any further painting from happening, events from being processed, and anything else that happens inside the `EDT`.

That's why you never perform long running operations on `EDT`, but use a `SwingWorker` or other mechanism instead.

Comment: correct. the infinite loop does not let the paint function finish

Comment: Where can I find out more about SwingWorker? My target is to generate random rectangles with g.fillRect().

Comment: Take the whole [Swing Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). You'll learn plenty of things and won't run into problems every 15 minutes when you have a solid base of knowledge.

Comment: @Firedan1176 Whenever somebody suggests a standard Java class to use, read about it in the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html).