# Thread.sleep() crashes my GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

My Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(delay)) command in my ButtonListener class crashes my GUI. Any ideas? The program is supposed to add people to an ArrayList, then randomly select them and display them at a random time between 0 and the timeText JTextField, and it works until I add the sleep command. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MyProgram extends AppClass{
  protected int x,y,width,height;
  protected Color color;
  private ArrayList<String> people = new ArrayList<String>(); 
  private static JLabel person;
  private Timer timer;
  private ButtonListener listener;
  private Random rand = new Random();
  private JLabel addPeople;
  private JTextField newPerson;
  private JTextField timeText;

  private Font font1 = new Font("Arial",1,17);
  private Font font2 = new Font("Arial",1,65);

  public MyProgram(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,800));

    people.add("me");
    people.add("john");
    people.add("greg");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    newPerson = new JTextField(2);
    newPerson.setFont(font1);
    addPeople = new JLabel("Add people:");
    addPeople.setFont(font1);
    person = new JLabel();
    person.setFont(font2);
    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.setFont(font1);
    JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    startButton.setFont(font1);
    timeText = new JTextField(2);
    timeText.setFont(font1);
    JLabel time = new JLabel("Maximum time between draws:");
    time.setFont(font1);

    listener = new ButtonListener();
    addButton.addActionListener(listener);
    startButton.addActionListener(listener);

    panel.add(addPeople);
    panel.add(newPerson);
    panel.add(addButton);
    panel.add(time);
    panel.add(timeText);
    panel.add(startButton);
    panel.add(person);

    add(panel);
  }

  private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
      JButton button = (JButton) ae.getSource();

      if(button.getText().equals("Add")){
        people.add(newPerson.getText());
        System.out.println(newPerson.getText());
        System.out.println("also worked");

      }else if(button.getText().equals("Start")){
        int delay = Integer.parseInt(timeText.getText());
        for(;;){
        person.setText(people.get(rand.nextInt(people.size())));
        try{
        Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(delay)); // the problem
      }catch(Exception error){
        System.out.println("Error");
      }
          }
      }
    }
  }
  }
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AppClass extends JPanel{

  public static void main(String [] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Get());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("My Program");

   }
}
```

Comment: well you are making your GUI sleep

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215968/java-thread-sleep-puts-swing-ui-to-sleep-too (btw, you already imported `javax.swing.Timer`, why not use it ...)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one thread that modifies the UI. This is by design, because it means that, even with the many sources of events that a UI could receive, it is impossible for concurrency bugs to corrupt the UI state.

There is only one thread that modifies the UI. That includes:

- Receiving mouse events.
- Receiving keyboard events.
- Processing requests to repaint.
- Processing UI timers.

Among many others.

If you're in code that modifies the UI, then you must be on the UI thread (else, you have a bug). If you're on the UI thread and you call `Sleep()`, then the UI thread stops doing things.

It'll stop responding to requests to repaint. It'll stop responding to keyboard events, mouse events, etc.

Instead, you have to use a forms timer to perform an animation. When someone clicks your "Start" button, you would set the first value, save off the rest of the values, and then start your timer, and then let the UI thread keep processing.

Each time the timer fires, you advance the state - you update the UI with the next value you want to show. You continue this until you've shown all values, and then stop the timer and release your state that told you where you were in the animation.

Yeah, you're just setting the text on some component, but this still falls under the animation pattern.

Be careful though - if your UI is closed while the animation timer is still running, you'll try to modify a UI that is gone. So now your UI code has to be careful to stop the animation timer if it's still running when the UI is closed.

Comment: How do I implement the timer? Thanks for your help

Comment: In the handler for when your start button is clicked, parse your delay and then start a swing timer with that delay. When the swing timer fires, modify the UI: pick a random person and call `person.setText()`. When your UI begins its shutdown, make sure the timer is disabled if it is not already disabled.

Answer (score -1):

actually, you are execute your gui into same thread and when you are use `Thread.sleep(delay)` you are also sleep you gui. so you have to use new thread for other processing.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no other thread that can solve this problem; a UI timer needs to be used. Introducing other threads will only result in UI concurrency bugs because you would be violating the constraint that only one thread ever reads or writes to the entire UI.